# How to batch convert .sph files to .wav with sox

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, sox

I have a directory with many folders containing hundreds of .SPH files. I need to convert all .SPH files into .wav format. I have adopted the following code:

> ```
> cd %~dp0
> mkdir converted
> FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox -t raw -s -2 -r 22050 -c 2 %%A "converted/%%~nA.wav"
> pause
> ```

However, it doesn't do anything on Windows 7. When I try the code on CMD inside a folder where some of .SPH are:

> sox *.SPH output.wav

It embeds all *.SPH into output.wav file, which is not what I want. I need name1.SPH to name1.wav, name2.SPH to name2.wav

Please help.

Comment: `sox *.sph output.wav` is supposed to convert all files into one so that doesn't work. So you need to try to get the above batch code to run correctly with the CMD window.

Answer (score 7):

For Linux consider this:

```
for f in *.SPH; do sox -t sph "$f" -b 16  -t wav "${f%.*}.wav"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7, I need to provide the entire path for the destination files, and the `mdkir` command got a permission error even though I was running as Administrator, so pre-make your destination directory and delete the `mkdir` command, and then your SOX command should look similar to this (with your own flags based on the conversion or edit you are trying to accomplish):

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox  -t raw -e mu-law -c 1 -r 8000 %%A c:\converted\%%~nA.wav
```

The cmd file should not be in the folder where the files are, it should be in the folder where SOX is installed, and then drag the files you want converted onto the cmd (or bat) file.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (*.sph) do sox "%%~a" "%%~na.wav"
```

Comment: do you mean `sox`  options?  Pls. add this by yourself.

Comment: No, I mean the code as it is doesn't work. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: set your `sph` folder, eg. `cd /d c:\data\sph`

Comment: and? why don't you kindly post entire working answer with details?

Answer (score 0):

Make a .bat file in your sox directory with the contents

```
cd %~dp0
for %%a in (*.sph) do sox "%%~a" "%%~na.wav"
pause
```

Select and drag the files that you want to convert onto this .bat file and the .wav files with the same names as the .sph files will appear in the same folder as the .sph files.